# Saving the Latitude and Longitude on map click to SQLite database not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to save the Latitude and Longitude to my SQLite database.  However it is not saving it and not getting any error messages.

This is my code I have so far:

```
dbHandler = new DBHandler(MapsActivity.this);
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

            String latLong = latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude;

            dbHandler.addNewLocation(latLong);

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And then the DBHandler class:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "locationsdb";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylocations";
private static final String ID_COL = "id";
private static final String NAME_LAT = "lat";

public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME_LAT + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void addNewLocation(String latLong) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME_LAT, latLong);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // this method is called to check if the table exists already.
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Then when I check the database there is nothing saved in it?

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Check the return value of `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)`. If it is not -1 then the row is added in the table.

Comment: Or use `insertOrThrow()` instead to get an exception with details why it might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `db.beginTransaction()` after calling `getWritableDatabase()` and use `db.endTransaction()` instead of `db.close()` in `addNewLocation(...)`.